# Extract data from IGC

Tags: ibm-information-server

Can anyone help: how can I extract  query results that I created in a CSV either by using web services or by API? I can manually do it by running a query and saving as a CSV, but here I had a request to automate it to a location.

I am open for any other options not including query if there are other options

Query Details:

Term Name

Term short description

Term Long description

Database table

Column

I have only access to the catalog.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can leverage on the REST API provided by IGC to get what you need.

The documentation is provided in this link - https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.bg.doc/topics/c_bgapi_intro_CP.html